# How to work with package repository mirrors frozen at a certain date?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, repository, apt-mirror

I set up a mirror for the usual Ubuntu repositories. This mirror only synchronizes when triggered manually for stability reasons.

The problem I have now is that I want to create a docker environment (for running builds on jenkins for example) that pulls packages from this mirror instead of the normal Ubuntu repositories. I start from something like arm64v8/ubuntu:bionic-20220531

But then I need to install wget, gnugp and apt-utils in order to be able to add the keys for my mirror repos then replace the links in /etc/apt/sources.list. There is no way around that other than first running apt update while having the Ubuntu repositories then apt install wget etc.

The problem then happens when I switch to my self-hosted mirror repositories that have older versions (few months old). When I then run apt update, I do get errors like the following:

```
Err:15 https://somecompany.com/repository/internal-bionic-ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main arm64 Packages
  File has unexpected size (1733949 != 1924418). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: ***.***.***.*** 443]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:1924418 [weak]
   - SHA256:d011c454986a032ecfcb30c07ebc9408bfc3f6efc1dd49f66acd29cafe1c18fe
   - SHA1:16d4e58d3f1b521e22e4d7d2790e574892d8a33e [weak]
   - MD5Sum:e3057ee4e08b91a37a21130acfedf13c [weak]
  Release file created at: Sat, 28 May 2022 03:24:25 +0000
```

Is there a way to tell Ubuntu to ignore this error?
Also, how can I force the system to downgrade to the newest versions available in the self-hosted repository?

Comment: It is not a feature of Ubuntu to have forced downgrades.

Comment: Sure, you can --force dpkg to treat errors as warnings and continue going (see `man dpkg`)...but it's a Bad Idea and your system might break if you do it too often. Downgrading has historically been a great way to break your system. Maybe downgrading will work, maybe not. The fundamental problem that you have seems similar to any PPA or third-party repo that doesn't keep up. The usual solution is to use VM or Container environments to keep your conflicting sources and versions separate.

Comment: It is something I only need to do once. I am stuck in a deadlock. How do you even pass arguments to apt update. Can you point me on a guide how to use dpkg arguments in apt-get ?